# How to remove index,php from CI project url to make clean url in nginx Hostwinds server, when CI project is inside subdirectory?

Tags: nginx, redirect, continuous-integration, subdirectory

"I'm setting up an Nginx server on Hostwinds for CI project which is in a subdirectory. Where I want to make a clean URL by removing index.php. Initially, this project was running on Apache server and with the help of .htaccess file, I have made a clean URL by removing index.php. But .htaccess file not works on the Nginx server. So, tell me what codes should I use to remove index.php from URL in 'Hostwinds' Server.

In subdirectory home page of projects opens but when you click on any of its links it will redirects you to 404 page.

I have tried various solution which is available on the internet but none of them worked for me. I have used this code inside nginx.conf file.
some of them:-

1)

```
location /category/subcategory {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /category/subcategory/index.php; 
    }
```

2)

```
location /subfoldername/ {
    root /usr/share/nginx/www/subfoldername;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
```

3)

```
location /api/ {
    alias  /var/www/api/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /api/index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_pass    backend;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
    }
```

4)

```
location /nested {
    alias /var/www/nested/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }



...http {...

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    #listen [::]:443 ssl http2 ipv6only=off;
    server_name example.com;
  location / {
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @backend;

  }



  location @backend {
    include proxy_params_common;
    # === MICRO CACHING ===
    # Comment the following line to disable 1 second micro-caching for dynamic 
  HTML content
    include proxy_params_dynamic;
  }



  # Enable browser cache for static content files (TTL is 1 hour)
  location ~* \.(?:json|xml|rss|atom)$ {
    include proxy_params_common;
    include proxy_params_static;
    expires 1h;
  }

  # Enable browser cache for CSS / JS (TTL is 30 days)
  location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
    include proxy_params_common;
    include proxy_params_static;
    expires 30d;
  }

  # Enable browser cache for images (TTL is 60 days)
  location ~* \.(?:ico|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|webp)$ {
    include proxy_params_common;
    include proxy_params_static;
    expires 60d;
  }

  # Enable browser cache for archives, documents & media files (TTL is 60 days)
  location ~* \. 
 (?:3gp|7z|avi|bmp|bz2|csv|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|flac|flv|gz|less|mid|midi|mka|mkv|mov|mp3|mp4|mpeg|mpg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|ogm|ogv|opus|pdf|ppt|pptx|rar|rtf|swf|tar|tbz|tgz|tiff|txz|wav|webm|wma|wmv|xls|xlsx|xz|zip)$ {
    set $CACHE_BYPASS_FOR_STATIC 1;
    include proxy_params_common;
    include proxy_params_static;
    expires 60d;
   }

  # Enable browser cache for fonts & fix @font-face cross-domain restriction (TTL is 60 days)
   location ~* \.(eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|svg|svgz)$ {
     include proxy_params_common;
    include proxy_params_static;
    expires 60d;
    #add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
   }

   # Prevent logging of favicon and robot request errors
   location = /favicon.ico {
    include proxy_params_common;
    include proxy_params_static;
    expires 60d;
    log_not_found off;
   }

   location = /robots.txt  {
    include proxy_params_common;
    include proxy_params_static;
    expires 1d;
    log_not_found off;
  }
  # Deny access to files like .htaccess or .htpasswd
  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }



}
```

Initially  link:- www.example.com/index.php/search-result

resulted in link:- www.example.com/search-result